# HTTP: Local variable being undefined after http-request

Tags: http, angular, typescript

When doing http calls, I would like to assign the incoming json to a local variable in my component and display it in the view.

Service:

```
getCases(){
    return this.http.get('someUrl')
        .map((res: Response) => res.json())
}
```

Component:

```
@Component({
    template: `
    <h1>Cases</h1>
    <hr>
    <br>
    <table>
        <tr *ngFor="let acase of cases" >
            <td>{{acase.name}}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
  `,
})

export class CaseListComponent implements OnInit {

    //local variable, need to have use of this!
    acase: Case;
    cases: Case[]; 

    constructor(public _service: CaseService, public _route: ActivatedRoute) {

    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this._service.getCases()
            .subscribe(cases => this.cases = cases);
        console.log(this.cases) // undefined!!
    }

    ngAfterContentInit() {
        console.log("cases: ", this.cases) //undefined!
    }

}
```

Comment: Everything is okay. Is there anything else you missed to point out? change public to private in constructor.

Comment: Can you also try throwing a type specifier at the end of your mapping?  Something like: `.map((res: Response) => res.json() as Case[])`

Comment: Okay try this,  `getCases():Observable<Case[]>{  
         return this.http.get('someUrl')...
       }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are assigning cases in the `callback` and the console.log will run before callback finishes. hence you are getting undefined.

```
ngOnInit() {
        this._service.getCases()
            .subscribe(cases => {
             this.cases = cases;
             console.log(this.cases) // will print values...
           });
        console.log(this.cases) // undefined!!
    }
```

Similar is case for `ngAfterContentInit` it will run before callback returns hence undefined.

Hope this helps!!

Comment: This absolutely did the trick! Like Alberto below said, the problem I wanted to articulate was to bind the JSON object to my view, like said, I'm a newbie, so I can't articulate my problem correctly ;) This solved my problem! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You could use this:

```
this.http.get('someurl').map((res: Response) => res.json()).subscribe(res => this.result = res);
```

Thanks to the subscribe function the code reacts to the result of the asynchronous request and deserializes the returned json into an object. Now, the returned JSON object is then bound to the view.